# MYSQL unique field based on other field + auto incriment

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a table having schema:

```
position, location.
```

I want the `position` to be unique to each `location` and also if I change the `position` of an item from 4 to 2, it will change what was at 2 to 3 and what was at 3 to 4.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE content_main(
    -> content_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> location TEXT,
    -> position INT NOT NULL,
    -> title TEXT,
    -> key_words TEXT,
    -> link TEXT,
    -> body TEXT,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (content_id));
```

```
Location      Position             Item
page1            1                  item1
page1            2                  item2
page1            3                  item3
page1            4                  item4
page2            1                  item5
page2            2                  item6
page2            3                  item7
page2            3                  item8
```

In this example item1 and item5 are in the same position but bc they are not on the same page that is ok. Item7 and item8 share a position and this is not ok bc they are on the same page. Also, if I `set position = 2 where item = 4;` I would like item2 to change to position 3 and item3 to change to position 4 automatically.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Can you please clarify a little about what you are trying to do?  Also what have you tried so far?   Maybe try showing a list of your table columns, data types, etc.